# Unregistered spammers should be deleted outright

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, spam-handling, spam

A lot of spam is posted by unregistered users. They only have accounts on one site, and their only contribution is a spam or troll post. In my opinion, such users are not worth keeping. How about if an unregistered user's first contribution ever gets deleted as spam or offensive, the user just gets automatically deleted. [This](https://askubuntu.com/users/1042335/william) is one of such users.

Here is an example of one of such users that should be deleted/destroyed https://askubuntu.com/users/1042335/william. If you are a moderator reading this, please delete that user.

Comment: Even some registered spammers persist. Here's [one](https://askubuntu.com/users/1040478/john-stro). Availability of staff to handle cases maybe a reason. I don't fully understand [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144879/629261) but you may like to read it. (I know your question is about *unregistered spammers*.)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165311/auto-delete-destroy-1-rep-user-when-their-post-is-deleted-as-spam

Comment: @MarkKirby Oops, I have apparently downvoted it and I wish I hadn't. I cannot remove downvote because I am suspended on meta for using sockpuppets, but even when it is over my vote will have been locked.

Comment: @MarkKirby More like a cross site duplicate.